# Will anyone be attending the NECSS Conference in April 2013?

Tags: discussion, conference

So, a few people up here at StackHQ have been talking about possibly attending this scientific skepticism conference!

If any of you are planning on attending **please reply to this post**! We could send you swag, maybe even set up a little social meetup/get-together kind of thing.

Check out [the official conference page](http://necss.org/) and please let me know if you're considering attending!

Comment: How about a plane ticket? :-)))))

Comment: Hahaha, @Sklivvz worth a shot. :P

Answer (score 5):

I am much closer to the venue than Sklivvz, so I *may* be able to go.  Unfortunately, my work life is very unpredictable and I could be prevented from going due to other high priority commitments.  If you don't mind waiting around a bit, so that I am more able to put a plan into my schedule, then I should be able to give a more definitive answer.

Some things that may help in driving the priority up on this would be that if you issued some sort of obligation on me to go.  For instance, if SE were to put up the conference fee, or if there was some sort of display table that I am needed to man, then I would have leverage with both my employer as well as my wife to say that not only would I like to go, but I am required to go.